# Understanding `pd.DataFrame.div()` and `pd.DataFrame.mul()`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how I can divide two dataframes and the `pd.DataFrame.div()` and `pd.DataFrame.mul()` documentation doesn't seem to explain things all that well for me. Below is a MWE

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ref = pd.DataFrame({'key':['a','b','c','d','e','h','z'], 'Values1':[1,2,3,4,5,'NaN','NaN']})
sub = pd.DataFrame({'key':['a','b','z','e','c','a'], 'Values2':[20,40,'Nan',60,80,100]})

ref = ref.set_index('key').astype('float64')
sub = ref.set_index('key').astype('float64')


### Create some sample dataframes of same size w/ different values

test1 = pd.concat([ref.reindex(sub.index.tolist()), sub], axis=1).astype('float64')
test2 = pd.concat([sub,sub*3],axis=1

### Sample Computations 

# 1) Divide test2 by test1, axis = 'index'

test2.div(test1, axis = 'index')

    Values1  Values2    Values2
key         
a    NaN     1.0    0.333333
b    NaN     1.0    0.333333
z    NaN     NaN    NaN
e    NaN     1.0    0.333333
c    NaN     1.0    0.333333
a    NaN     1.0    0.333333
```

What seems to be happening is that the .div() method takes each column of `test2` and divides it by the column of the same name in `test`. So the `.div()` is avoiding the `Values1` column, and then doing the division on the columns of similar name. What I am aiming to get is something akin to below:

```py
    Values1  Values2    
key         
a    0.05    0.33   
b    0.05    0.33   
z    NaN     NaN    
e    0.083   0.33   
c    0.038   0.33   
a    0.01    0.33
```

I can actually get the values that I want by doing `test1.values / test2.values`, but then I have to merge these values back into a dataframe which seems inefficient and suggests I might be doing something wrong in my attempts to use `.div()` or `.mul()`.

So I am hoping that someone could explain to me how the `.div()` method is actually working in this instance and why my result is not coming out as I think it should be coming out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns aren't the same. `test2` here has columns of `["Values2", "Values2"]` not `["Values1", "Values2"]`. See below with columns fixed. Also note you had a typo which I marked. You are also dividing 2 by 1 but your expected output is 1 by 2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ref = pd.DataFrame({'key':['a','b','c','d','e','h','z'], 'Values1':[1,2,3,4,5,'NaN','NaN']})
sub = pd.DataFrame({'key':['a','b','z','e','c','a'], 'Values2':[20,40,'Nan',60,80,100]})


ref = ref.set_index('key').astype('float64')
sub = sub.set_index('key').astype('float64') #fixed typo


### Create some sample dataframes of same size w/ different values

test1 = pd.concat([ref.reindex(sub.index.tolist()), sub], axis=1).astype('float64')
test2 = pd.concat([sub,sub*3],axis=1)
test2.columns=test1.columns #fix columns

### Sample Computations 

# 1) Divide test2 by test1, axis = 'index'

print(test1)

print(test2)

print(test2.div(test1))
#showing axis:
print(test2.div([1,2], axis = 'columns'))
print(test2.div([1,2,3,4,5,6], axis = 'index'))
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the types. So then the issue here is that the columns have to have exactly the same names? Is there a way to accomplish the same expected outputs with different column names while respecting the index position?

Comment: If the columns aren't the same then how would it know which columns to divide by?

Comment: I do not know, this is likely where my misunderstanding is. I thought that the `axis = 'index` option would look at each row and then divide the elements piece by piece. It seems like a common thing to have two different data frames with the same indexes and different columns.

Comment: See my edit. Axis was doing nothing here. Axis is when you are providing a single value for each row or column instead of a second dataframe.

Comment: OH. I think I understand now. the `.div()` for example passes down the list [1,2] from top to bottom and divides the individual elements.